# Which color is the best for wearing shirt for men?

Tags: fiqh, men, clothing

I can remember that a person told me that white is the colour for men to put on the shirts. Of course it is obvious that majority of people (Arab) use white Dishdashah (الدشداشه), so, perhaps it could confirm the issue, but I am looking for an authentic tradition concerning this matter to indicate that the best color is white (for men).

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him His family and companions)

> Ibn Abbas narrated that: The Messenger of Allah said: "Wear the white
>   among your garments, for indeed they are among the best of your
>   garments, and shroud your dead in them."(Tirmidhi)

And

> Samurah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Messenger of Allah
>   (ﷺ) said, 'Wear white clothes because they are the purest and they are
>   closest to modesty; and shroud the dead in it." [An- Nasa'i and
>   Al-Hakim].

Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) wore different colors in clothing, he wore white, black and green color turban However In Numerous Hadith we got to see Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) preferred and ask to wear white clothing.There is one more narration regarding likeness to green color,

> “The most beloved of colors to the Messenger of Allah (Allah’s peace
>   and blessings be upon him) was green.” [Tabarani, Mu’jam al-Awsat;
>   al-Bazzar, Musnad]

People of Paradise would be mainly in green color clothing as in Quran 18:31

**Those will have gardens of perpetual residence; beneath them rivers will flow. They will be adorned therein with bracelets of gold and will wear green garments of fine silk and brocade, reclining therein on adorned couches. Excellent is the reward, and good is the resting place.** (Quran)

Allah (Swt) and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Totally, a nice answer, especially as you said: People of Paradise would be mainly in green color clothing as in Quran 18:31 ___ God bless you